# Stream zip file in, pipe to unzip, pipe out?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, stream

I've done quite a bit of googling on this, and have come up short.

I currently have a Lambda function that streams a file from ftp (using promise-ftp) then pipes it to s3 (using s3-streams). This works just fine.

I've come across an issue where the files are zipped, and I would like to unzip them before I upload them to s3. I've had 0 luck getting any of the unzip utilities (which are all really just node-unzip under the hood) to work with local files. I've had even worse luck piping things through to unzip (at the best, I've made it save files recursively inside directories with the same name on my local machine during testing).

The relevant code I've tried is:

```js
stream.pipe(unzip.Extract({path: '/tmp/'}).pipe(toS3Stream)
```

Which gives me ENOENT. The same thing with unzip.Parse() gives me 'unreadable' errors. I've had unlink permissions errors. I'm at a loss...

I'm willing to save items to the lambda temporarily, but I can't even seem to get that to work.

Edit: Also, to be very clear: these are **.zip** files, not .gz, so zlib will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently following node-unzip's examples with the if/else blocks was my issue. The following works (tested locally and on Lambda with 30+ files):

```js
ftp.connect({ host: ftpHost, user: ftpUser, password: ftpPassword })
                .then(serverMessage => {
                    return ftp.get('/directory/' + fileName);
                })
                .then(stream => {
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        logger.info('Streaming file from FTP')
                        stream.once('error', rej);
                        stream.once('close', res);
                        stream.pipe(FS.createWriteStream('/tmp/'+fileName));
                    });
                }).then(() => {
                    logger.info('Closing FTP connection')
                    // Unzip the file and pipe it to S3
                    FS.createReadStream('/tmp/'+fileName).pipe(UNZIP.Parse())
                    .on('entry', obj => obj.pipe(toS3Stream))
                    .on('close', () => {
                        resolve('File unzipped and written to S3.')
                    })
                    resolve('FTP closed');
                    return ftp.end();
                })
```